# What does Secure Boot protect against?

Tags: uefi, secure-boot

As far as I understand, Secure Boot protects system from running code not signed by a specific vendor(s) during early boot stages.

In  order to attempt an attack on the bootloader in the first place, an attacker would need either:

1. Boot from their own boot media, if firmware or boot manager settings are not protected. This would require physical access to the device.
2. Get root access to the system, which would allow modifying ESP and EFI variables.
3. Perform such modifications without root access by means of some vulnerability.

In any case, looks like we already are in a bigger trouble.

But as soon as system has started, Secure Boot does not control further course of execution. It's the job of the OS to ensure the secure environment. This is of course true for an uncompromised system in control of its legitimate owner.

However, if an attacker succeeds in any of the steps above, why would they need to install a modified bootloader (assuming they are aware that Secure Boot is enabled)? What prevents them from installing a copy (maybe stripped down) of the legit OS bootloader and kernel, signed by the vendor? (Since `db` typically contains vendor keys, not file hashes, it doesn't even have to be the same version). E.g. all binaries would be correctly signed, the difference would be in system setting (user accounts, startup scripts, etc.). When such an OS starts, the attacker will get root access to the system, and may even pass control to the original system in order to confuse user.

So I don't see what Secure Boot adds here on top of protecting firmware, bootloader settings and root account. Could you please give an example of an attack that is countered by Secure Boot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So I don't see what Secure Boot adds here on top of protecting firmware, bootloader settings and root account. Could you please give an example of an attack that is countered by Secure Boot?

So, first things first: obviously if the attacker can turn off Secure Boot (or install their own trusted keys), it doesn't prevent anything. Thus you either need to require authorization before overwriting firmware settings or prevent disabling Secure Boot altogether (different devices take different options here). "Require authorization" can look like a lot of different things; sometimes it's simply that there's no way to do it from within a running OS (in which case an attacker with physical access may be able - assuming there's no other protections - but malware on the device would not) but usually it implies a setup password or similar.

---

Secure Boot has a number of uses, but the most legitimate (IMO) ones are for protecting user devices against two classes of attacks: boot-time rootkits (sometimes called "bootkits") and compromised disk encryption boot code. Secure Boot is also used to lock down devices shipped to customers.

Bootkits are straightforward in principle: if you can gain code execution before the legitimate OS even starts, you can completely own the system, undetectably, forever (potentially even if the disk is reformatted, depending on where the bootkit is installed). There are various ways to do this, such as abusing hardware virtualization support to install your own hypervisor and lift the OS into a guest VM that only thinks it's running on bare metal. This is much worse than normal malware, where simply deleting malicious files and at most reinstalling the OS is sufficient to clean the device.

Disk encryption code is a narrower but similarly important target; the disk encryption requires some code that runs before the OS boots (because the OS's installation is itself encrypted), and if the attacker modifies that pre-OS boot code (which can't, itself, be encrypted or you'd have a catch-22) then they can capture your disk decryption key, passwords, etc.

Device lockdown - which applies to everything from consumer devices like smartphones and game consoles to industrial and telecommunication hardware used by corporations or governments - is an attempt to prevent the customer from modifying or repurposing the hardware or extracting secrets from the device (usually in combination with encryption). This is used to implement DRM, anti-cheat protections (e.g. on consoles), firmware encryption (where the customer does *not* have the key, or any credential to derive it from) where the firmware contains private keys or other secrets, or even just IP that the vendor doesn't want reverse-engineered, and so on.

With those use cases in mind, let's look at what Secure Boot *does*.

---

> why would [the attacker] need to install a modified bootloader (assuming they are aware that Secure Boot is enabled)? What prevents them from installing a copy (maybe stripped down) of the legit OS bootloader and kernel, signed by the vendor?

Well, why is your vendor signing bootloaders that do what the attacker wants? Unless the attacker stole the vendor's private key, they can't install anything that the vendor didn't sign (or at least, it won't run), and presumably the vendor hasn't signed a bootkit that shims the OS boot process and sends all your credentials and Bitcoin wallet keys to North Korea, or that lets you run pirated games.

As a side note, what form of "stripped down" are you imagining wouldn't count as "modified"?

> But as soon as system has started, Secure Boot does not control further course of execution. It's the job of the OS to ensure the secure environment.

Strictly speaking true, but in a sense false. Secure Boot doesn't control further execution, but it does constrain it to only those operations that are allowed by an OS that the signed bootloader allowed. As with many such systems, it's a chain of trust. The hardware prevents installing a compromised firmware, the firmware verifies the bootloader, the bootloader verifies the OS, and the OS verifies whatever runs upon it. Or not, in some cases; maybe you the user run everything as Administrator/root and have turned off/never installed any anti-malware or other software security features, and the OS either doesn't have any software restriction features or you disabled/never installed those either. But you *could* instead have a mostly-general-purpose OS that nonetheless only allows executing software with a trusted signature (this is what Windows RT was, and is approximately what you get with Windows' "S mode" or if you leave on the MacOS option that prevents running anything that wasn't installed from their Store).

Without Secure Boot, a device owner - or anybody else with access to the device - could install (or boot off removable media) their own OS without those restrictions. Or in the case of disk encryption software, pull an "evil maid" attack, trick the user into entering their decryption credentials into the compromised system, and then steal the data off the disk (this is a case where Secure Boot can protect a system even without constraining post-bootloader code execution). Considering that disk encryption is explicitly for the protection of data *when the attacker has physical access*, that's pretty significant!

Comment: Thank you. So, as far as I get from your answer, Secure Boot requires additional protection on the OS level, otherwise the chain of trust is broken. What about OS's that give their owners more freedom, like Linux?

Comment: _why is your vendor signing bootloaders that do what the attacker wants?_ - Well, Linux vendors signs the software that does what the *user* wants (within their login privilege level, of course), and once those privileges are obtained, it is hard to tell whether a certain action is intended (user's) or malicious (attacker's). Getting your own wallet keys, sending data to North Korea, and even installing completely different OS are valid user actions from this perspective.

Comment: @nevermind in that case attackers presumably don't need to install a new bootloader at all, right? If you're using a bootloader that doesn't verify the OS, or an OS that doesn't verify the software, then all that Secure Boot gets you is protection against boot-time attacks. But that's not nothing! Mostly, it would still allow a greater degree of security for disk encryption. You could also create your own chain of trust (signed bootloader and kernel + init, at least) and enable Secure Boot trusting _only your own signing key_ (plus lock down the firmware setup) as a bootkit protection.